# Cut a set of ranges of integers from another set of ranges

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays of ranges in this form:

```
wanted = {[10, 15], [20, 25]}
cut = {[5, 12], [22, 24]}
```

So `wanted` is an array of two elements (ranges) - `[10, 15]` and `[20, 25]`.

Each of the two arrays fulfil these conditions:

1. It is sorted by the first value in each range of integers
2. The ranges will never overlap (e.g. `[10, 15]`, `[15, 25]` is not possible)
3. This also means that each range is unique within the array (no `[1, 5]`, `[1, 5]`)
4. If a range is just one integer wide, it will be displayed as `[5, 5]` (beginning and end are equal)

I now want to obtain an array of ranges, where all ranges from `cut` have been removed from the ranges in `wanted`.

```
result = {[13, 15], [20, 21], [25, 25]}
```

Is there some brilliant algorithm better / easier / faster than the below?

> For each element in `wanted`, compare that element to one element after another from `cut` until the element from `cut` ends above the element from `wanted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say there are `n` elements in `wanted` and `m` elements in `cut`.

The following is an `O(m + n)` algorithm to perform the required task:

```
j = 1
result = {}
for i = 1:n
  // go to next cut while current cut ends before current item
  while j <= m && cut[j].end < wanted[i].start
    j++
  // cut after item, thus no overlap
  if j > m || cut[j].start > wanted[i].end
    result += (wanted[i].start, wanted[i].end)
  else // overlap
    // extract from start to cut start
    if cut[j].start > wanted[i].start
      result += (wanted[i].start, cut[j].start-1)
    // extract from cut end to end
    if cut[j].end < wanted[i].end
      result += (cut[j].end+1, wanted[i].end)
      j++
```

Note that, asymptotically, you can't do better than `O(m + n)`, since it should be reasonably easy to prove that you need to look at every element (in the worst case).

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for in an answer. I think you are missing the case when the elements from cut and wanted are identical, but maybe that wasn't clear from my question. Other than that, this pretty much is the solution I came up with, in tidy form. +1 :)

Comment: @Squeezy I could be wrong, but I don't think it will be a problem. It will just iterate through and not add anything (is that what you want?) - looks like, at each for-loop iteration, the `while` will loop once (0 times in the first iteration) and none of the conditions for any of the 3 if-statements will hold.

Answer (score 0):

What is the biggest size which `wanted` and `cut` may be? Comparing the "first element from `wanted`" with "*all* from `cut`" will take O(n^2) run time, i.e. very slow if the arrays are large.

It would be much faster to work over each array in parallel until you reach the end of both, something like a "merge".

Comment: Under reallife circumstances I do not expect either of them to exceed about 30 pairs maximum. I need to fix that part about "all" from cut though, you just compare until the pair to be cut ends higher than your current pair in wanted.

Comment: If neither of them exceeds 30 pairs, I wouldn't bother doing anything more complicated than the simple algorithm you describe. It will be fast.